# Cramer's rule for eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the above doesn't exist, but do bear with me. I need estimates/formulas for entries of certain eigenvectors and Cramer's rule keeps popping up in my mind. So, what can play an anlogous role in this case?

Comment: Maybe your question will ring a bell for someone else, but this strikes me as being a bit vague. What kind of estimates/formulas do you need?

Comment: If you know an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the associated eigenvector is the kernel of $A-\lambda I$ and you can use Cramer-like formulas to express this kernel (tell me if you are interested in more detail, but it's not so hard). If you don't know the eigenvalue, then I don't think you can do much. Determinants are rational functions and eigenvalues/eigenvectors are not, so I am afraid everything that you can do will essentially be computing the characteristic polynomial and finding its roots.

Comment: Yes, I am interested..:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $u$ is a unit eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a Hermitian matrix
$$ A_n = \begin{pmatrix} a & X^* \\\\ X & A_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$
with $a$ a real number, $X$ an $n-1$-dimensional row vector, and $A_{n-1}$ an $n-1 \times n-1$ Hermitian matrix, then (provided that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A_{n-1}$) the magnitude of the first coefficient $u_1$ of $u$ is given by the formula

$$ |u_1|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + \| (A_{n-1} - \lambda)^{-1} X \|^2};$$

see e.g. Lemma 41 of [this paper of mine](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0510) with Van Vu (and we learned of this formula from [this previous paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1730) of Erdos, Schlein, and Yau).  Similarly for other components of $u$.  The proof proceeds by expanding out the bottom $n-1$ components of the eigenvalue equation $A_n u = \lambda u$ and using the resulting equation and the formula $\|u\|^2=1$ to solve for $u_1$.

The expression $\| (A_{n-1} - \lambda)^{-1} X \|$ can be expanded further by a number of formulae (e.g. Cramer's rule); in our applications, it turns out that the spectral theorem applied to $A_{n-1}$ is useful.  The above identity is particularly useful for establishing delocalisation of eigenvectors for random matrices (i.e. that the energy of the coefficients of a unit vector are spread out almost uniformly).  It may seem a bit strange that the top left coefficient $a$ plays no explicit role in this formula, but it is implicitly present due to its influence on the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

The phase $u_1$ of the unit eigenvector does not have a clean formula, because eigenvectors are only determined up to phase rotations unless one somehow selects an artificial normalisation.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting and I'll be sure to delve into it!

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+normal+form+calculator

Let $J$ be the Jordan normal  form of a matrix $A$ (that is , $A=PJP^{-1}$ ) . Then the  $V_{An}$ eigenvectors of $A$ can be written as $PV_{Jn}$ , where $V_{Jn}$ are the eigenvectors of $J$  . Although calculating $J$ and $P$ can be rather complicated , calculating the eigenvectors of $J$ is trivial .

Also recomend reading this

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/DownDets.pdf

At least to me it seems like the best tutorial on linear algebra out there .(edit:I did not intend for this to sound  condescending or anything , I recommend that paper to anyone who does linear algebra)

Comment: It's alright, I figured out the intended meaning after following the link... :)

P.S.
Ergo: the downvotes aren't from me...